# haproxy - can it manage sessions on its own?

Tags: java, session, tomcat, haproxy

Is it possible to manage Sessions with ha proxy?
If so, does it mean i can ignore creating sessions in my tomcat web application ?

If i want to have 3 different tomcats without sticky session i will have to cluster them and replicate sessions. however-  if haproxy can manage the sessions instead it will be preferable.

is it possible to do?

so far iv'e managed to get setup a standard tomcat clustering with session replication, but i would like haproxy to manage the sessions if possibe.

Answer (score 0):

No. Application sessions can't be managed in HAProxy. The [HAProxy documentation](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/#docs) doesn't mention it.

Don't confuse it with **`appsession`**, this refers to session persistence a.k.a. sticky sessions.